# How to move AJAX'd content in Javascript w/ Moovweb SDK?

Tags: javascript, ajax, moovweb

So sometimes when working with the Moovweb SDK a client will AJAX in a content spot, but it will be in the incorrect area?

I cannot use tritium to move this content, because the area I want to move it to is inserted after page load!

Example:

```
<div class="where-i-want-to-move-it"></div>

<div class="content-area-i-want-it-moved-from">
  <p class="content-i-want-moved">Hi! This was ajaxed in at a later date!</p>
</div>
```

How can I detect that this p tag was added through AJAX when I cannot control their JS to fire a specific event or fire a different call back?

Comment: I’m pretty sure there has to be a way for you to just tell it where you want it to go in the first place…

Comment: Hey Minitech, in the moovweb SDK you're relying on your client's JS. So sometimes, you can't just move the ajax container, because it will cause a javascript error. So you have to wait for the content to be populated first, then move it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to listen to node changes -- see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11546242/966018) -- and assuming you can target the correct mutation event, move the content manually in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Our firm avoids using MutationObserver because [older versions of Android and IE don't recognize it](http://caniuse.com/#search=MutationObserver).

Instead, [we have begun implementing CSS Animations](https://moovwebconfluence.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TS/Never+use+DOMNodeInserted+again).  You can insert CSS into your .ts file to assign animation @keyframes to an element.  We then add a JS listener to listen for "webkitAnimationStart".  So now when the AJAX'd content loads, the listener is instantly triggered, and we can now manipulate the new DOM using JS.

It is an excellent trick, and is cross-browser compliant when fully implemented.